Output random chunk of file divided by an arbitrary character in Bash Script
I have a text file of quotes. I want to output one quote every time I open bash through WSL. I know I need to put my commands in .bashrc, my issue is knowing which command to use. I found one called shuf that sounds like it'd work well, but my quotes contain newlines and I haven't found an option that allows me to divide the quote file by an arbitrary character.
Essentially, I need to convert this Python code into Bash Script
import random

with open("csciquotes.txt", 'r') as f:
    result = random.choice(f.read().split("%"))
    print(result)

The issue is finding how to mimic .split("%").
I've read several questions and haven't found anything, as well as some guides.

[edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Dont assume that the people who can best help you write a bash script are also python experts who MAY be able to get all the information they need about what they need to do in bash by reading your python script. Also, a quote is normally a single quote (') or a double quote (") so it's not obvious why your script is splitting on a percent character (%), please explain that and tell us which type of quote you're using. Add all information in the question, not comments

A quotes file with % as a delimiter? Bet you can use fortune with it.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/36523/creating-a-fortunes-file

Is there some reason you don't want to use the normal fortune program for this?

I would have posted a comment, but I do not have permission yet, so I added this rough answer.
Assuming that the percentage % char is used for "quotation" separator,
you can have themreplaced with newlines, and newlines replaced by another unused character (for example the caret ^ could be a good choice)
storing the results in a temporary file
cat memorable_citations.txt | tr '[\n%]' '[^\n]' > /tmp/$$
then you can use the shuf tool you mentioned on the temporary file /tmp/temp$$
($$ is the PID of the shell so in general /tmp/temp$$ should be a safe name)
and save the random quote in a RANDOM_QUOTE variable, then delete the temporary file /tmp/temp$$
and finally send RANDOM_QUOTE to the screen  after performing the inverse transformation
echo "$RANDOM_QUOTE" | tr '^' '\n'
P.S.:
I know that the usage of a temporary file should be avoided whenever possible, but this solution was just a draft

Why cat input | instead of just <input? Granted, tr doesn't try to do anything smarter that would benefit from a seekable handle, but as so many other tools (sort, tail, wc, &c) do benefit, the latter is a better habit to be in.

You can use awk to extract records from a file using arbitrary record delimiters. You have a file that looks something like this:
This is
quote 1
%
This is
quote 2
%
This is
quote 3

By telling awk that % is the record separator, we can extract specific quotes. E.g.:
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo === quote $i ===;  awk -vRS=% -vquotenum=$i 'NR==quotenum {print}' quotes.txt; done
=== quote 1 ===
This is
quote 1

=== quote 2 ===

This is
quote 2

=== quote 3 ===

This is
quote 3

The only thing we need to know is the number of quotes contained in the file. We can get that with grep -c. To extract a random quote from the file, we can combine the above to do something like this:
# Get the total number of quotes
numquotes=$(grep -c '^%$' quotes.txt)

# Pick a random number in that range
quotenum=$(((RANDOM % numquotes) + 1))

# Extract the selected quote
awk -vRS=% -vquotenum=$quotenum 'NR==quotenum {print}' quotes.txt


Thank you! I've imbedded numquotes into quotenum since it's used once and I don't care too much about readability. I've also used \n%\n to split on, since I learned it allows me more flexibility

We can easily read the file with Awk using \n%\n as a record separator.
We don't know in advance how many records there, are and would like to choose a random one with a equal probability.
Let's say that the file is very large, so that we don't want keep the quotes in an array in memory.
This very problem in computer science is answered by Reservoir Sampling.
We might as well go for the optimal "Algorithm L".
Since we only want one quote, and not a random sample of k entries, in other words k is 1, it simplifies: randomInteger(1,k) simplifies to randomInteger(1,1) which simplifies to 1.
Here is an attempt to translate the algorithm to a GNU Awk. We have to rearrange the logic because we don't control the loop over the records, and we don't have random access over the input records S[]. Other than that, we will keep the same variable names as used in the Algorithm L description in the referenced Wikipedia page:
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
  RS = "\n%\n"
  # seed the PRNG
  srand(PROCINFO["pid"] + systime())
  # select first record to be R
  i = 1
  # initialize random parameter W
  W = rand()
}

# we have reached record i
NR == i {
  # replace selection
  R = $0
  # choose next record
  i += int(log(rand())/log(1 - W)) + 1
  # shrink W to lower probability
  W *= rand()
}

END {
  print R
}

GNU Awk's srand, if not given an argument, uses the time of day as a seed. That has only one second granularity, so we use the process ID and time of day to get different random numbers in consecutive runs that occur within the same second.
I seem to have a %-separated Fortunes file on my system, but one specifically for the VLC program, filled with VLC-related quotes, with lots of material from some #videolan IRC channel:
$ ./fortunes.awk fortunes.txt
< nefrir> btw, anyone *really* opposed to temporary (1 month at most) breakage of video splitter (wall, clone, panoramix) and some vout filters (ie some mode of deinterlacing, opencv, autocrop) in master ?
< j-b> NO
< j-b> nefrir: seriously, if people care, they can branch
< Dark_Shikari> isn't this what local branches are for?
< j-b> Dark_Shikari: indeed. But you could consider master as nefrir 's local branch :)
< Dark_Shikari> lol
 -- #videolan

$ ./fortunes.awk fortunes.txt
<Xtophe> is there any centralien alive ?
<thedj> i hope so. haven't heard a thing about a nuke explosion in Paris

  -- #videolan

In the initial revision of this program, I noticed that when it was given a file with two entries, it was choosing the first entry more often. I wrote a program to test this more and discovered empirically that it was choosing the first entry with a 75% probability rather than 50%. This was due to a bug. I had these two statements in the code in reverse:
  # choose next record
  i += int(log(rand())/log(1 - W)) + 1
  # shrink W to lower probability
  W *= rand()

My test program is used like this:
$ ./test.sh x x y
538
$ ./test.sh x x y z
315
$ ./test.sh y x y z
325

It takes two or more arguments. The first argument is the key item to count. The remaining items specify the items to choose from. The program feeds those items to the sampling program 1000 times, and counts how many time that program produces the key item. For instance ./test.sh y x y z producing 325 means that our program selected the y item out of x y z, 325 times out of 1000, which is close to the expected one third.
Here is test.sh:
#!/bin/bash

key=$1
shift
arg1=$1
shift
args=("${@}")

c=0

for ((i = 0; i < 1000; i++)) ; do
  res=$((printf "%s\n" "$arg1"; printf "%%\n%s\n" "${args[@]}") | ./fortunes.awk)
  case "$res" in
  ( "$key" ) : $((c++)) ;;
  esac
done

echo $c


Thank you! I'll use your \n%\n with the other awk response, since I can more easily understand it

@Kaz : maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't exp(log(rand())) just cancel each other out, and it should output something very close to the original output from rand() (assuming the unlikely scenario where no precision is lost after being routed through 2 transcendental functions)

@RAREKpopManifesto Thanks for pointing that out; I will look into this, revisiting the sources and all.

@RAREKpopManifesto  Ah yes, okay. The original Algorithm L has a k parameter which we set to 1, since we are only getting one random item.  The original formula is exp(log(random())/k).  So indeed, since k is 1, we can simplify that.

version without awk - check amount of lines with wc, generate random number and read line.
DICTIONARY_SIZE=$(wc -l <file.txt)
RANDOM_LINE=$((1 + $RANDOM % $DICTIONARY_SIZE))
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $RANDOM_WORD ]; do
    read LINE
    counter=$(($counter+1))
done<file.txt
echo $LINE

